# Android monkey runner mark checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, monkeyrunner

I have a simple monkeyrunner script opening a custom app, and I need to mark specific checkboxes in the application.
So far I haven't managed to move up and down and press them using the usual:

```
MonkeyDevice.press("DPAD_DOWN", MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
MonkeyDevice.press("DPAD_CENTER", MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

How can I, if at all, mark a checkbox by its ID as designated by the apps xml?

Thanks in advance
Noam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) a try.

`AndroidViewClient` adds to monkeyrunner the ability of

- finding Views by ID, very much like you normally do in your Android Activity (using `ViewClient.findViewById()`)
- obtaining the value for almost any of the Views properties (using for example `View.isChecked()` or `View.mText()`)
- sending touch events to the `Views` by simply invoking `View.touch()`

You can find a working example in [monkeyrunner: interacting with the Views](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html).

Comment: I tried to use AndroidViewClient to send touch events on a view. But View.touch() did not touch the desired view. It touched another area. This is because the coordinates were relative to the parent. i could not figure out how to get passed this issue. I even asked a question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953927/how-to-click-on-a-view-which-contains-specified-text-using-monkeyrunner-and-andr

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Are you using the latest AndroidViewClient version? AFAIK all the cases were addressed. Should you have a test case where the latest version is failing please create an issue at https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/issues?sort=created&state=open